# Eliminar elementos repetidos del DOM

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Quisiera eliminar elementos repetidos del DOM

```
$arrTitles=array(
                    1=>"<h2 id='elemento1'>Titulo pueblo 1</h2>",
                    2=>"<h2 id='elemento2'>Titulo pueblo 2</h2>",
                    3=>"<h2 id='elemento3'>Titulo pueblo 3</h2>",);
```

Aca muestro en el DOM con un bucle

```
$var1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `$table_name` WHERE localidades like 'Pueblos%'");
foreach ($var1 as $var){
$result .=''.$arrTitles[1];.'
<p>'.$var.' </p>
<p>Texto de descripción</p>
';}

$template = '{data}';

return $content.str_replace('{data}', $result, $template);
    
}

return $content;
```

Hago un sql que me muestra todos los datos de la base de datos, entonces con el array le pongo un titulo pero se pone un titulo por cada dato, quisiera que solo se viera el primer titulo, gracias de antemano (:

Comment: Creo que el problema que tiene es que tiene el bucle/ciclo para construir la linea de titulos anidado dentro del bucle/ciclo que recorre la data que desea mostrar. Debería colocar el fragmento de codigo que genera los titulos antes y fuera del bucle/ciclo que recorre los datos obtenidos desde la base de datos. De ese modo no debe modificar el DOM

Comment: @MauricioOrtega elimine mi respuesta anterior, ya lo solucione gracias a tu comentario (: como el $result anida todos los datos en bucles aunque se repita, puedo poner $result = <h1> Titulo </h1> fuera del bucle y se agrega al resultado, gracias!

Comment: Es satisfactorio saber que mi comentarlo, sin ser respuesta, le haya orientado en la solucion. Puedes calificar positivamente tales comentarios, esos puntos.positivos nos alientan a responder y, como en este caso, comentar.